# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException after setRollbackOnly

Tags: transactions, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I have in a Containter-managed transaction- bean something like this:

```java
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Resource
  private EJBContext ejbContext;


  public void testTransaction() {
    Model model1 = new Model();
    em.persist(model1);

    ejbContext.setRollbackOnly();

    Model model2 = new Model();
    em.persist(model2);//the line the problem
  }
```

In the last line (with the problem) a TransactionRequiredException is thrown:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```

but in the [Mastering EJB 4th edition](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1369778/Free-Book-Mastering-Enterprise-JavaBeans-30) book (search for "Doomed Transactions" or go to page 299) it is explained so, as it would not be thrown any such exceptions, and instead you should check for `ejbContext.getRollbackOnly()` only before resource-hungry operations.

Of course I could in this simple example avoid the problem by throwing an Exception annotated with `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)`, but I just wonder what I miss.

Answer (score 0):

By calling ejbContext.setRollbackOnly() you have aborted the current transaction started by container. After that there is no transaction that can be associated for  em.persist(model2);. So you get an exception. 
To check whether the transaction is active use  getRollbackOnly() method in ejbcontext which will return false.

Comment: Well, this is the only explanation for my case, but in the documentation of the ´setRollBackOnly()´ it is nothing written about the unassocation of the current transaction (and neither in the EJB 3.1 Specs)  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#setRollbackOnly%28%29 So I could supose this is a BUG. I tried it in Jboss 7.1.1. With what AS did you try it?